# Wordpress Memory Issue

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-leaks

I'm getting an error on a couple of my single product pages in my shop, the error is as follows:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes) in /home4/casualselect/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woozone/lib/scripts/amazon/aaAmazonWS.class.php on line 964

I don't know much about code, or even know where to begin when looking at the script causing the problem. Any insight into this would be very much appreciated.

Update:

I have WP MEMORY LIMIT set to 256M and WP MAX MEMORY LIMIT set to 512M, still doesn't do the trick. It has to do with that script in the woozone plugin, I'm almost sure of it.

And I don't really want to increase my memory limit anymore, just to put a bandage over the problem that still exists. If anything, it's probably making my site slower too so I want to learn how to fix it.

Another thing too, maybe this will help, when W3 Total Cache is activated, all the single products that displayed that error message at the bottom, become just blank white pages. And vice versa, when W3 Total Cache is deactivated, the blank white pages have that error message on the bottom. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to try editing your `wp-config.php` file. By adding or editing the following line:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

If that does the trick you will be ok but be sure to perhaps look at this document if the issue goes beyond WP.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/increasing-the-wordpress-memory-limit/

Comment: Ya, I already did that and unfortunately, still the same issue. I also updated my original question with some more info, maybe it will help. Thanks for the help, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: what happens when you disable the plugin?

Comment: Well all my products and everything disappear. This website i'm building is an Amazon affiliate website, and this plugin is an Amazon affiliate plugin.

Comment: Its too broad of a question, you need to investigate and explore the line that its telling you and show us what that line is causing the error. Its far too hard to diagnose form the information provided, have you contacted the plugin vendor?

Comment: Ya, they seem to think that it's because my server dosen't have enough memory, and that I should upgrade to 1gb, which seems kind of absurd.Ill dig into the code more, see what comes up.